# DDD: Do item counts belong in domain model?

Tags: repository, domain-driven-design, cqrs

Say you are modeling a forum and you are doing your best to make use of DDD and CQRS (just the separate read model part). You have:

```
Category {
    int id;
    string name;
}

Post {
    int id;
    int categoryId;
    string content;
}
```

Every time that a new post has been created a domain event `PostCreated` is raised.

Now, our view wants to project count of posts for each category. My domain doesn't care about count. I think I have two options:

1. Listen for `PostCreated` on the read model side and increment the count using something like `CategoryQueryHandler.incrimentCount(categoryId)`.
2. Listen for `PostCreated` on domain side and increment the count using something like `CategoryRepo.incrimentCount(categoryId)`.

The same question goes for all the other counts like number of posts by user, number of comments in a post, etc. If I don't use these counts anywhere except my views should I just have my query handlers take care of persisting them?

And finally if one of my domain services will ever want to have a count of posts in category do I have to implement the count property onto the category domain model or can that service simply use read model query to get that count or alternatively a repository query such as `CategoryRepo.getPostCount(categoryId)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My domain doesn't care about count.

This is equivalent to saying that you don't have any invariant that requires or manages the count.  Which means that there isn't an aggregate where count makes sense, so the count shouldn't be in your domain model.

Implement it as a count of PostCreated events, as you suggest, or by running a query against the Post store, or.... whatever works for you.

> If I don't use these counts anywhere except my views should I just have my query handlers take care of persisting them?

That, or anything else in the read model -- but you don't even need that much if your read model supports something like `select categoryId, count(*) from posts...`

> domain services will ever want to have a count of posts in category

That's a pretty strange thing for a *domain service* to want to do.  Domain services are generally stateless query support - typically they are used by an aggregate to answer some question during command processing.  They don't actually enforce any business invariant themselves, they just support an aggregate in doing so.

Querying the read model for counts to be used by the write model doesn't make sense, on two levels.  First, that the data in the read model is stale - any answer you get from that query can change between the moment that you complete the query and the moment when you attempt to commit the current transaction.  Second, once you've determined that stale data is useful, there's no particular reason to prefer the stale data observed during the transaction to stale data prior.  Which is to say, if the data is stale anyway, you might as well pass it to the aggregate as a command argument, rather than hiding it in a domain service.

OTOH, if your domain needs it -- if there is some business invariant that constraints count, or one that uses the count to constrain something else -- then that invariant needs to be captured in some *aggregate* that controls the count state.

*Edit*

Consider two transactions running concurrently.  In transaction A, Aggregate id:1 running a command that requires the count of objects, but the aggregate doesn't control that count.  In transaction B, Aggregate id:2 is being created, which changes the count.

Simple case, the two transactions happen by luck to occur in contiguous blocks

```
A: beginTransaction
A: aggregate(id:1).validate(repository.readCount())
A: repository.save(aggregate(id:1))
A: commit
// aggregate(id:1) is currently valid

B: beginTransaction
B: aggregate(id:2) = aggregate.new
B: repository.save(aggregate(id:2))
B: commit
// Is aggregate(id:1) still in a valid state?
```

I represent that, if aggregate(id:1) is still in a valid state, then its validity doesn't depend on the timeliness of the repository.readCount() -- using the count prior to the beginning of the transaction would have been just as good.

If aggregate(id:1) is not in a valid state, then its validity depends on data outside its own boundary, which means that the domain model is wrong.

In the more complicated case, the two transactions can be running concurrently, which means that we might see the save of aggregate(id:2) happen between the read of the count and the save of aggregate(id:1), like so

```
A: beginTransaction
A: aggregate(id:1).validate(repository.readCount())
// aggregate(id:1) is valid

B: beginTransaction
B: aggregate(id:2) = aggregate.new
B: repository.save(aggregate(id:2))
B: commit

A: repository.save(aggregate(id:1))
A: commit
```

It may be useful to consider also why having a single aggregate that controls the state fixes the problem.  Let's change this example up, so that we have a single aggregate with two entities....

```
A: beginTransaction
A: aggregate(version:0).entity(id:1).validate(aggregate(version:0).readCount())
// entity(id:1) is valid

B: beginTransaction
B: entity(id:2) = entity.new
B: aggregate(version:0).add(entity(id:2))
B: repository.save(aggregate(version:0))
B: commit

A: repository.save(aggregate(version:0))
A: commit
// throws VersionConflictException
```

*Edit*

The notion that the commit (or the save, if you prefer) can throw is an important one.  It highlights that the model is a separate entity from the system of record.  In the easy cases, the model prevents invalid writes and the system of record prevents conflicting writes.

The pragmatic answer may be to allow this distinction to blur.  Trying to apply a constraint to the count is an example of *Set Validation*.  The domain model is going to have trouble with that unless a representation of the set lies within an aggregate boundary.  But relational databases tend to be good at sets - if your system of record happens to be a relational store, you may be able to maintain the integrity of the set by using database constraints/triggers.

- [Greg Young on Set Validation and Eventual Consistency](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/08/12/eventual-consistency-and-set-validation/)

How you approach any problem like this should be based on an understanding of the business impact of the particular failure.  Mitigation, rather than prevention, may be more appropriate.

Comment: Couldn't the invariant that uses count to constrain something, use `CategoryRepo.getPostCount(categoryId)` to get that count without any aggregate controlling count state? Because technically the count information is already there just by counting the number of posts. I'm basing my reasoning on what Eric Evans said about repositories in his book: "Although most queries return an object or a collection of objects, it also fits within the concept to return some types of summary calculations, such as an object count, or a sum of a numerical attribute that was intended by the model to be tallied."

Comment: @DenisPshenov Eric Evans wrote this at a time when CQRS didn't exist. Nowadays you would put `getPostCount()` on a read model Facade, not a command-side repository.

Comment: Yes, I understand you would put in on a read model to be used by your views. But if domain also needed that count why couldn't we put it into the repository as well. Look at it this way - what if some invariant wants to know total number of categories in our system. Would you create another aggregate that controls the count of categories? Or would you just ask your repository to tell you how many categories it has?

Comment: @DenisPshenov If the domain needs the count, it will use the same read model. CQRS means you're model is specialised, not that one belongs to the domain and the other doesn't.

Comment: Your modelling is wrong, in DDD the **aggregate is the unit of work**, there is no outside transaction wrapping aggregates. Mixing CRUD solutions and DDD patterns is one of the most common anti patterns.

Comment: @MikeSW, I thought it was a common advice not to use read models in your write side (ie. commands). If that is not true, should one at least maintain a separate read model for commands from the one that is used for views?

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason, I grasp the general idea of what you are trying to explain with the transactions example but I can't think of any case where your proposed solution to use a single aggregate will really solve the problem you show, because a newly created entity in transaction `C` could still make previous ones invalid. Honestly, I think that if a new entity could make previous ones invalid then we should not even be able to create it. I would argue that in your first transactions snippet, `(id:1)` will stay valid but `(id:2)` is invalid if it is created in way which invalidates `(id:1)`.

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason, looking at it one more time, all of your examples will make a lot more sense if you validate entity before saving it against the `count`. If you do that then your proposed solution is indeed correct and so far the only one to solve the concurrency issues that you illustrated. If you don't validate before saving then I think the whole example breaks down due to issues in the comment above.

Comment: @DenisPshenov A read model is a read model. A command _use case_ can use a read model for one concept to get the data required for the command model of another concept. The reason why we separate things is so that we can use a simpler model for the cases where we only want to read stuff. You don't have a big command part and another separated read part in your app. C/Q applies at the most granular level i.e the model representing **one** concept.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to counts of things I think one has to consider if you actually need to save the count to the DB or not.

In my view in most cases you do not need to save counts unless their calculation is very expensive. So I would not have a `CategoryQueryHandler.incrementCount` or `CategoryRepo.incrementCount`.

I would just have a `PostService.getPostCount(categoryId)` that runs a query like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Post 
WHERE CategoryId=categoryId
```

and then call it when your `PostCreated` event fires.

Comment: For the read side it is better to have those counts already there for performance reasons. For domain one could use something like what you describe because writes are rare in my system.